# Try to get Pixel Color

Tags: android, pixel, android-bitmap, getcolor

Im trying to get the Color of a pixel. I have the following in my `OnCreate`:

```
bitmap = img.getDrawingCache();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(5,5);

int r = Color.red(pixel);
int g = Color.green(pixel);
int b = Color.blue(pixel);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"R("+r+"G"+g+"b"+b, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Unfortunately something is missing because my app is crashing.

Comment: share your logcat log.

Answer (score 0):

**Side-comment:** you are just creating the Toast, you are not showing it.
If you are calling it from the OnCreate method:

```
Toast.makeText(this,"R("+r+"G"+g+"b"+b, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Oh thanks but thats not the main reason, why its not working